# Stoic Aphorisms?

Tags: stoicism

What are some poignant aphorisms that a practitioner of stoicism could internalize to help remain stoic throughout their day.

Think motivational calendar and you'll know what I'm after.

I'm aware that asking list questions is problematic, but I can't help but feel that there is an axiomatic way of understanding practical Stoicism.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on your challenges.  For instance, if you find it really tough to put up with other people, then your set of useful aphorisms would differ than if you were really attached to the opinions of others.

Have you read Aurelius' [Meditations](http://archive.org/search.php?query=creator%3A%22Marcus%20Aurelius%22) or Epictetus' [Enchridion](http://classics.mit.edu/Epictetus/epicench.html)?  Both are very aphoristic-friendly, so you can extract passages that "speak to you" as your Stoic aphorisms.

With that said, the most useful aphorism (IMO) is...

> Events cannot hurt me, only how I choose to react to events can hurt me.

Every other aphorism can be seen as a specific application of this.

Comment: I'm making my way through them atm. Thank you for the response.